# MySQL How to continually create unique files to output?

Tags: mysql, file-io

**I have the following storedprocedure**

```
DELIMITER ##
CREATE PROCEDURE exportFile()
BEGIN

Select * from Sample
INTO OUTFILE '~/Sample.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

END ##
DELIMITER ;
```

- After first call to the stored procedure you will get `ERROR 1086 (HY000): File '~/Sample.csv' already exists` 
  -- And rightfully so.
- I need to continually keep creating new files. (ie. Sample1.csv, Sample2.csv, Sample3.csv ... and so on) on every call.

**Question: How do I do that?**

Answer (score 6):

Why not append a timestamp to the file ?

Here an example appending timestamp to the file :

```
DELIMITER ##
CREATE PROCEDURE exportFile()
BEGIN

Select * from Sample
INTO OUTFILE CONCAT('~/Sample', CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT( your_date_field, '%d%m%Y') ,'.csv'))
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

END ##
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Mysql don't permit to use functions or variables as filename

Comment: @aleroot I've been fighting to do this but I get an error 4200 for syntax when trying to do this as piotrekkr implicated

Comment: If you can use mysqldump, the best way (imo) would be use mysqldump with tab option: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tab and with `--fields-terminated-by=..., --fields-enclosed-by=..., --fields-optionally-enclosed-by=..., --fields-escaped-by=...`

Comment: @piotrekkr can you set me up generically with the above example.

Answer (score 3):

I arrived at a similar requirement for debugging a recursive stored proc.

This worked for me:

```
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * INTO OUTFILE ',"'", CONCAT('Result',FLOOR(1000+RAND()*9999)),'.txt',"'",' FROM TempTable112');
PREPARE stmt2 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;
```

I use xampp and got the output at C:\xampp\mysql\data\myfolder.